# Create Windows Shortcut to Launch Symantec Endpoint Protection 12.1 LiveUpdate

Tags: windows-7, symantec

I previously used LUALL.exe to launch an older version of Symantec Endpoint protection, but that is now gone in version 12.1.  The tool can still be opened from within the Symantec software, but I am trying to set it up to launch directly from a shortcut to minimize the steps.  There is a different screen I can launch that might do the same thing (SepLiveUpdate.exe), but it is commandline and lacks the nice UI.

Does anyone know how to directly get the nice UI to pop up?

Answer (score 2):

I am Chetan Savade from Symantec Technical Support Team.

Liveupdate is inbuild in SEP 12.1 client so luall.exe won't work on SEP client. This is a architecture change in SEP 12.1 but luall.exe is supported on SEPM machine.

However now you can run it through SEP Client GUI.

Best Regards,
Chetan

Comment: Does SepLiveUpdate.exe do the same thing, except in a commandline UI?